# How can my C native program detect if it's running in Android platform

Tags: android, environment-variables, native

I am coding some C app on my Linux laptop, but at office, will occasionally port it to an android platform using ndk-build.  Every time I switch platforms, I need to change a bunch of paths specific to either my laptop or the android platform. So I currently set it up something like:

```
#define ANDROID 1

#ifdef ANDROID
  #define ....
  #define ... bunch of stuff specific to android
#else
  #define ... bunch of stuff specific to my laptop. 
#endif
```

Each time I have to remember to comment/uncomment out the #define ANDROID line. It's getting to be irritating.  Is there any way to directly detect if I am running in an android environment or a regular linux environment and then setup my paths accordingly ?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you not just set a flag at build to specify the environment it was compiled for? Isn't MAKE used to automate these kind of repetitive tasks?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for. But please excuse my naivety in this.  How do I set an environment variable in MAKE or Android.mk and have that detected in my program? Do I just do something like CFLAGS = -g -<some env option here> ANDROID ? What's the syntax to do this? I suppose I can then use something like getenv('platform') to detect where the code is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put something like this in your Android.mk

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -DANDROID
```

Where -D is a flag to pre-define a symbol and ANDROID is the symbol to define

Then your #ifdef ANDROID blocks in code will work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you develop. You could use a parameter to a Makefile or if you use Eclipse then  you may have a project per platform. In each project, the respective variable corresponding to the target platform is set.